# How to add user for samba share through a shell script

Tags: command-line, samba, user-management

Normally when i want to add a user for samba shared folder i use this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

and then this pops out

```
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
```

and now I want to do this in a script but so that it doesn't stop there and ask me to insert password

this is my script:

```
##################################################################
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /var/www/html/test

tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf << EOF
[test]

comment = Test folder
path = /var/www/html/test
browsable = yes
valid users = tester
read only = no
EOF

smbpasswd -a tester
password
password
```

...How can i hard code the password?

Comment: Use expect - http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

Comment: that is 169 MB big package that i need to give me 2 lines of code....it's just too much....until someone gives a better solution i will type it in manually

Comment: Don't use sudo in your script, call the script with sudo `sudo /path/to/script`. , test if directory exists `[ ! -d /var/www/html/test ] && mkdir -p /var/www/html/test` , note the `-p` option. You can also test if /var/www/html/test already is within the conf file and if not add it (you should be able to figure it out).

Comment: Try google samba+scritp+to+add+user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own from [this website](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/samba-benutzer-per-shell-skript-anlegen/)

So the basic thing is that if you want to make a script for adding a specific user to the samba share goes like this:

This part of script is 'standard' and doesn't need to be changed except for the path of the folder you want to share:

```
##################################################################
#!/bin/bash

# make a folder if it doesn't exist
[ ! -d /var/www/html/test ] && mkdir -p /var/www/html/test

# append these lines at the end of the /etc/samba/smb.conf file
tee -a /etc/samba/smb.conf << EOF
[test]

comment = Test folder
path = /var/www/html/test
browsable = yes
valid users = tester
read only = no
EOF
```

and now if you want to:

#### add an existing user: append this to the 'standard script' above:

```
username='<existing_user_name>'
(echo "<password_for_user>"; sleep 1; echo "<password_for_user>" ) | sudo smbpasswd -s -a $username
```

#### add a new user that doesn't exist in OS: append this to 'standard script' above:

```
username='<new_user_name>'
useradd -m $username
(echo "<password_for_user>"; sleep 1; echo "<password_for_user>";) | passwd $username
(echo "<password_for_user>"; sleep 1; echo "<password_for_user>" ) | sudo smbpasswd -s -a $username
```

Comment: Ok i will do it today. I just woke up

Comment: I hope this is explained better and that the user who down voted me will give a feedback if it's still not good?